# Android Linkify from HTML in TextView

Tags: android, linkify

I have HTML with standard links which correspond to commands I'd like to handle.

```
This is <a href="CMD:nice">a command</a>.
```

I populate a TextView with Html.fromHtml()

How can I use the Android Linkify system to convert the  links to Linkify'ed ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found that the WikiNotes example project from Google does exactly that. It uses the Linkify infrastructure with a Provider and MIMIE type to load the right Activity.